# Start function again automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do, that whenever my page "test.php" loads, then my function will start whenever the user clicks at `#start`

When the user navigates away from the advertisement (to another tab for example), then the function will stop. (working)

Whenever the user then go back to the tab (test.php), the function should start again. I just can't seem to find what to do.. Currently I have this:

```
  $("body").on('click', '#start', function()
                    {
                        $('#website').focus();
                        $('.message').html('<div class="alert info"><b id="seconds">'+parseFloat($seconds-$current_second)+'</b> seconds remaining.</div>');
                        if($timer !== null) return;
                        $timer = setInterval(function()
                        {
                            if($current_second==$seconds)
                            {
                                clearInterval($timer);
                                $('body').addClass('done');
                                $('.message').html('<div class="alert info">Validating advertisement&hellip;</div>');

                                $.post('index.php?i=v&p=k&token=' + token,{'key': key,'token':token,'time':time,'stime':stime},
                                        function (data) {
                                            proccessData(data);
                                        });
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var $counter_bar_width = $('#bar').innerWidth();


                                //$('#bar').css('width',parseFloat($counter_bar_width+$width_per_second).toFixed(2));
                                var left = (<?php echo $time; ?>-$current_second)*1000;
                                $current_second++;
                                $("#seconds").text(parseFloat($seconds-$current_second));
                                $('#bar').animate({
                                width:'100%'
                                }, left);   


                            }
                        },1000); 
                    });


                    var vis = (function(){
                        var stateKey, eventKey, keys = {
                            hidden: "visibilitychange",
                            webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
                            mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
                            msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
                        };
                        for (stateKey in keys) {
                            if (stateKey in document) {
                                eventKey = keys[stateKey];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        return function(c) {
                            if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
                            return !document[stateKey];
                        }
                    })();


                        var handler = function(){ 
                          // calling vis() with no arguments will return a boolean


                          if (vis()) {
                            //Visible.
    Page tab is now visible. Now the timer and the bar should start moving / counting down again.


                          } else {
                            //Not visible.                      
                            var myDiv = $("#bar");
                            myDiv.clearQueue();
                            myDiv.stop();   
                            clearInterval($timer);
                            $timer = null
                          }
                        }

                        // if a handler is passed, it gets bound to the event
                        vis(handler);       
                    });
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you’re prefixing variables with `$`?

Comment: Not really. I'm not that familiar with jQuery, just saw it online. Made sense to me.

Comment: It  kinda makes sense when you are referring to jQuery objects as a reminder. But not every variable. Example: `var $jqElement = $('#someElement');` but on the contrary `var ordinaryVar = 0;`.

Comment: Alright. Do any of you guys a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to bind a click handler when the user is on your tab, and unbind it when they have navigated to another tab.

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    bindClick();
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    unBindClick();
});

function bindClick()
{
    $('#start').on('click.tester', function(e){
        // Do your stuff here
    })
}

function unBindClick()
{
    $('#start').unbind('click.tester');
}
```

This will bind an event listener for click events on #start when the window has gained focus (your tab is active), and will unbind the same event listener (the .tester bit prepended on the click keyword ensures you're unbinding the correct listener)

Another option which prevents the need to bind/rebind would be to bind the click listener once, and only do anything if *something* is true (in this case, if the window has focus)

```
$('#start').on('click', function(e){

    // This currently tests for browser focus, but could test for just about anything
    if (document.hasFocus()) {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Or, if you'd like to save state somewhere, you can bind the click event listener, and pause/resume it's functionality with window focus and blur events. If you're going to go this route it probably makes sense to maintain the bindings and state in one central object.

```
$('#start').on('click', function(e){

    $(window).blur(function(e){
        // Pause functionality

    }).focus(function(e){
        // Regain functionality

    });

    // Do Stuff (probably need to save state somewhere)

});
```